# In Linux, how does a bootloader find a bootable disk?

Tags: linux, grub2

I am using CentOS 7 and have attached multiple disks to it. I know my OS, kernel, initramfs etc. resides at "/dev/sda" and that is the bootable disk. But how does grub2 deduce that? Does it check all the attached disks one by one?

Comment: When GRUB is loaded into memory, the *"bootable disk"* has already been identified.  I.E. GRUB was loaded from that bootable drive.  The bootable drive (not *"disk"*) is controlled by the boot order of the BIOS/UEFI and active partition on that drive.

Answer (score 1):

Technically: Linux doesn't find any bootable disk, because by the time Linux is running, the bootloader has done its job - which is:

- copy Linux from a file into RAM somewhere
- copy the initramfs from a file into RAM somewhere
- on some architectures like ARM - copy additional things like a device tree or architecture descriptor into RAM somewhere
- pass control to the first location in RAM where Linux was copied, and now the bootloader is no longer active.

Moderm UEFI firmware as well as things on non-x86 platforms like U-Boot will have "boot entries" stored in the firmware - a boot entry contains a storage device and a filename, and the firmware will go in order and load/run the first  file it finds.  You change the order by going into UEFI settings and making changes, or using a utility in your OS to alter UEFI NVRAM settings.

Now the thing about UEFI on x86 is that it will load a single binary into RAM, but usually Linux needs at least an initramfs to boot as well (though this is not a strict requirement of Linux).

Also historically x86 had more primitive firmware (BIOS) that simply loaded the first sector off of a storage device (order determined by BIOS settings) and didn't even try to look for/load files.

So that's why on most Linux systems, the thing that UEFI actually loads (which is the thing obeying boot order/searching for bootable devices) is GRUB - it's a common bootloader platform for Linux (and other operating systems if desired) that will actually do a lot of the pre-boot stuff that *should* be in firmware but isn't for various reasons, and also gives you an environment to do stuff before an operating system is loaded.

When installing Linux, the installer will configure GRUB by generating a config file that GRUB can get to, and will add entries into GRUB's menu that tell GRUB where to go to load the kernel and initramfs.  Multiple entries are possible and even common - for example Debian will install a second menu item for a rescue kernel - roughly equivalent to Windows Safe Mode.  But these are all set by the installer when Linux is installed, and you're reaching those options after UEFI has done its thing.

(BTW one of the things I liked about U-Boot was that it will load the kernel and initramfs directly, so GRUB wasn't needed at all.  But that was an ARM device with customizable firmware).

Windows has its own "GRUB" called `winload.exe` that does things Windows needs, and optionally provides pre-boot menu options, before boot that the firmware doesn't do either.  You use `bcdedit` to change menu options there.  Earlier versions of Windows than Vista used NTLDR and things could be configured with the C:\boot.ini file IIRC.

Linux doesn't require GRUB - for a long time a simpler bootloader called LILO (Linux Loader) was used and some distributions probably still use it.

Comment: Thanks for the comment and both you and @sawdust are totally right to say that by the time grub comes into play, the bootable drive has already been identified; which is why it is possible to locate and copy kernel and initramfs files into the memory in the first place. I understand this now. I should have mentioned BIOS (or UEFI) instead of grub/grub2.